# How to reduce execution time of a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a query which is given below. My doubt is regarding its record fetching time. Is there any better way to fetch records than this method?

```
select   product_code,product_name,price,taxPercentage,discount_type,discount_amount,prof it_type,profit_amount,purchase_code, qty 
from (
   select distinct p.product_code,p.product_name,pid.price,t.percentage as      taxPercentage,p.discount_type,p.discount_amount,p.profit_type,p.profit_amount,
    pu.purchase_code,pid.quantity+isnull(sum(sri.quantity),0) -isnull(sum(si.quantity),0) -isnull(sum(pri.quantity),0) as qty 
   from tbl_product p 
   left join tbl_purchase_item pid on p.product_code=pid.product_code 
   left join tbl_purchase pu on pu.purchase_code=pid.purchase_code 
   left join tbl_tax t on t.tax_code=p.tax_code
   left join tbl_sale_item si on si.product_code=p.product_code
   left join tbl_sale s on s.sale_code=si.sale_code
   left join tbl_sale_return sr on sr.sale_code=s.sale_code
   left join tbl_sale_return_item sri on      sri.sale_return_code=sr.sale_return_code
   left join tbl_purchase_return_item pri on pri.purchase_code=pu.purchase_code
   group by p.product_code,p.product_name,pid.price,t.percentage,p.discount_type,p.discount_amount,p.profit_type,p.profit_amount,pu.purchase_code,pid.quantity
) as abc 
where qty >0
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT combined with GROUP BY?

Comment: Your doubt? What's the fetching time? Have you checked the Execution plan/explain output?

Comment: You have too many left joins, a DISTINCT clause which can be avoided and a GROUP clause with too many fields. Do you really need all the data from each of these tables ? In the sub query, you're fetching a computed column named qty, and outside the query you're adding a `WHERE qty = 0`. You can include the WHERE clause in the sub query itself, that will remove all the rows where qty is 0. 
Please update your question with `EXPLAIN <query>` output. It will inform about the number of rows fetched using each section of query.

Comment: Also, [SE DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) seems like a better place to ask this question :)

Comment: Please show a query plan and schema information. The outer "where" clause can probably be replaced by a "having" clause. "Distinct" may be hiding a bug which you're not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how your database looks like. You have too many joins and I guess that is the root of the slowness.

First, make sure you have indexed all the columns used in the joins.

If that does not help, try to do some [Denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). That way you will introduce some redundancy in your database, but the read time will improve.

Answer (score 0):

1. Join Smaller table with larger table
2. consider an index on the table